# I want fix drop down menu as header of all page in asp.net(Without master page concept)

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, header

I am using role based log in and load menu items according in drop down.
but this same menu with drop down facility want in all asp.net page.
same time i don't want to use master page concept.Is there any way to do this ??

Comment: It would be helpful to know why you don't want to use a MasterPage.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot or do not want to use a Master Page then I'd suggest a custom User Control.